# Error Boundary with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have setup my routes to wrap all components with an Error Boundary

```
function renderComponentWithErrorBoundary(Component) {
  return () => {
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Component />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )
  }
}

<Route path="/" exact render={renderComponentWithErrorBoundary(HomePage)} />
<Route path="/video/:programId/episode/:episodeId" render={renderComponentWithErrorBoundary(EpisodeVideoPage)} />
```

Problem now is once an error is caught the boundary seem to apply to all routes, meaning no matter which route I navigate to, I still see the error boundary error state. I thought in this setup it should be isolated to the particular component?

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
      shouldFocus: false
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.hasError && this.state.shouldFocus) {
      focusElem(document.querySelector('#appNavLive'))
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          shouldFocus: false
        })
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({
      hasError: true,
      shouldFocus: true
    })
    console.log(`[ERROR] ${error.message}`)
    console.log('[ERROR]', info)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <div
          id="app-error-boundary"
          data-focusable
          tabIndex="0"
          ref={elem => { this.elem = elem }}
          data-focus-left="appNavLive">
          An Error Occurred
        </div>
      )
    }
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I was thinking of doing the same.

Answer (score 6):

In react when you have several components of the same type that needs to maintain their own state, you need to give them a unique key property. So you should give your ErrorBoundary components a key property that is unique for the specific component it incapsulates.

Comment: That's not correct is it? Aren't you mixing how the render algorithm requires a `key` on list elements to recognize them as the same with this question?

Comment: Hm. Yes that sound correct. Though I'm pretty sure that I had exactly the problem described above and solved it adding a key property on the ErrorBoundary. But I must admit that the code in question is somewhat far behind at the moment so there might be more to it ..

Comment: This does seem to be the problem here.  When you navigate after an error, you're replacing one `<ErrorBoundary />` with another `<ErrorBoundary />`, and React doesn't re-render it as it thinks the elements are the same.  By adding a `key`, React can tell that they are different elements so it deletes the first `<ErrorBoundary />` (that is showing an error) and renders the new one in its place (which is not showing an error).