# Why does routing stop working even when using an ErrorBoundary?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, routes, react-router

Our app use an [ErrorBoundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) to catch errors. This works fine and it presents an error message at the defined place, as it should. But after the error has manifested itself routing stops working, essentially breaking the app!

I find it a bit strange, considering that the app otherwise seems to work: DevTools shows `routing/LOCATION_CHANGED` actions being dispatched (I'm listening to the `history` object) when I click links and/or use the back button, and the url is updated, but no new routes/screens are being rendered.

Since React and Redux is working, I've come to point at React Router, since it's the main component dealing with routing. Does anyone know how I can stop it from breaking?

**An example error**

This error is from a connected component and happens in the `mapStateToProps`

```
connectAdvanced.js?fe33:242 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3528' of undefined
    at getUserInRoleById (VM7787 users-reducer.js:108)
    at getUserByUserInRoleId (VM7787 users-reducer.js:110)
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (VM8180 EncounterNotesHistoryItem.jsx:360)
```

Followed by

```
The above error occurred in the <Connect(EncounterNotesHistoryItem)> component:
    in Connect(EncounterNotesHistoryItem)
    in div
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (created by EncounterNotesHistory)
    in div (created by EncounterNotesHistory)
```

**Component hierarchy (selected pieces)**

App.jsx

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter history={customHistory} dispatch={dispatch}>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <Route exact path="/appinfo" component={AppInfoScreen} />
      <Redirect exact from="/" to={`/encounter?attenderId=${userId}`} />
      <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchScreen} />
      <Route exact path="/search/:searchText" component={SearchScreen} />
      // and so on
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

**Dependencies**

```
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-dom": "^16.9.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router": "^5.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"reselect": "^3.0.1",
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Added an example error that is quite typical, as it mostly happens in the data loading part.

Comment: Where are you wrapping your ErrorBoundary component, at the component level or at the Root, if root then it should not work as error occured and you would essentially need to reload the page, if at the component level, then that particular component should not work anymore

Comment: @Rikin I added an example of my top-level component hierarchy. So you are saying that I would need to add my error boundary "inside" of the routing definitions? Kind of makes sense, but would be really naste to add one handler per route :-/ Alternatively I would need to make a kind of `ErrorHandlingRoute` HOC that wrapped each component with my error boundary. How would you solve this?

Comment: I think your HOC idea seems the route I would go since I would personally would not like individual routes to handle their own way, unless they need something custom. But yeah the mental model for ErrorBoundary is like try/catch block at a component level and everything wrapped inside it, if it fails then those wrapped component should not work as it already got caught in the `componentDidCatch`

Comment: Found a similiar question that [did exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49850331/200987), but he had some weird shared error state, for some reason. Haven't tried myself, though. Find it strange that this isn't covered anywhere.

Comment: Here's the example of HOC: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind `Error boundaries` is to provide an elegant way to deal with [cryptic errors](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).

> Error boundaries work like a JavaScript catch {} block, but for components.

This means that everytime an error is thrown inside a component's tree that is wrapped by an `Error boundary` the whole tree will be replaced by the `fallback` value (a custom error message for example). So everytime one of your `Route` components throws an error the whole tree will be considered with error and will no longer be rendered (unmounted).

You could wrap individual `Routes` in an error boundary to protect them from crashing the rest of the application (including the other `Routes`).

See more about the ideal granularity of your `Error boundaries` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#where-to-place-error-boundaries)

Comment: while your comment was correct, I found the real issue preventing me from getting this working (even if implementing your suggestion): the `Switch` component wrapping my routes. Without this, routing starts to work. Could you have a look to see if you understand why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056211/why-does-using-an-error-boundary-disable-routing-when-the-routes-are-inside-of-a